# FontAwesome element too large?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On http://live.clars.com/m/search/ I copied over the header from http://www.clarstestsite.com.php54-3.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/

For some reason the elements "#navigation ul.nav > li a" on the former are wider than on he latter design, but when I check the styles everything seems to be exactly the same.

I think I've narrowed it down to the "#navigation ul.nav li.parent > a:after" element which appears larger on the former than it does on the latter, even though when I check the computed styles in chrome developer tools they both have the exact same parameters as far as I can tell.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show the relevant code using stack snippet.

Comment: <a href="http://www.clarstestsite.com.php54-3.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/category/upcoming-auction/">Auctions</a>

But it won't help unless you look at the links I've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Its the size of the arrows. If you look closely the dropdown arrows appear bigger. They will automatically move the text. The text isn't wider or large its just not positioned in the same place because of the arrows. If I'm completely missing the point of the question completely due to my own stupidity (its happened alot) please respond and I will gladly spend some time of this.

Comment: No you're absolutely correct, and that's basically what I outlined in my original question: "I think I've narrowed it down to the "#navigation ul.nav li.parent > a:after" element which appears larger on the former than it does on the latter, even though when I check the computed styles in chrome developer tools they both have the exact same parameters as far as I can tell."

Answer (score 0):

instead add

```
#navigation ul.nav > li a{font-size:10px}
```

your font icon size will reduce

Comment: When I do that all elements, including the words become way tinier than in the original.